# Quickbook Online: 2500: [Invalid Reference Id : Categories cannot be used in transactions.]

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

We are using consolibyte/quickbooks-php wrapper its working fine with required activities. But when we tried to create an invoice from our crm its giving an 2500: Invalid Reference error.

We tried retrieving invoice record from quickbook online using the same value as well the same ref and created an invoice record in our crm when we try to sync the information its giving me the same error 2500. But when we run a script making all the objects making manual (Instead of loop) and then run the code its creating an invoice.

```html
$InvoiceService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Invoice();
 $Invoice = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Invoice();
 $Invoice->setDocNumber('HELLO11');
 $Invoice->setTxnDate($invoice['invoice_date']);
 $Invoice->setCurrencyRef('INR');
 $Invoice->setCurrencyRef_name('Indian Rupee');
 $Invoice->setExchangeRate('1');
 $Invoice->setCustomerRef($invoice['billing_acc_qb_id']);
 $Invoice->setCurrencyRef_name($invoice['billing_account']);
 $Invoice->setCustomerMemo('checking with script');
 $Invoice->setDueDate($invoice['due_date']);
 $Invoice->setTotalAmt($invoice['total_amount']);
 $Invoice->setHomeTotalAmt($invoice['total_amount']);
 $Invoice->setBalance($invoice['total_amount']);
 $Invoice->setDeposit('0');
 foreach($line_item as $row)
 {
 $ln=$row['line_item'];
 $line_amount=($ln['product_unit_price']*$ln['product_qty']);
 $Line = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Line();
 $Line->setDetailType('SalesItemLineDetail');
 $Line->setAmount($line_amount);
 $Line->setDescription($row['tax_info']['Item_description']);
 
 $SalesItemLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesItemLineDetail();
 $SalesItemLineDetail->setItemRef($ln['part_number']);
 $SalesItemLineDetail->setUnitPrice(number_format((float)$ln['product_unit_price'], 2, '.', ''));
 $SalesItemLineDetail->setQty($ln['product_qty']);
 $SalesItemLineDetail->setTaxCodeRef($row['tax_info']['TaxCode']);
 $Line->addSalesItemLineDetail($SalesItemLineDetail);
 $Invoice->addLine($Line);
 }
 $TxnTaxDetail= new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_TxnTaxDetail();
 $TxnTaxDetail->setTotalTax($invoice['tax_amount']);
 //foreach($line_item as $row)
 //{
 //$tax_detail=$row['tax_info']['tax_detail'];
 foreach($tax_arr as $row)
 {
  foreach($row as $tax_dtl)
  { 
  $TaxLine= new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_TaxLine();
  $TaxLine->setAmount($tax_dtl['TaxAmt']);
  $TaxLine->setDetailType('TaxLineDetail');
  $TaxLineDetail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_TaxLineDetail();
  $TaxLineDetail->setTaxRateRef($tax_dtl['TaxRateRef']);
  $TaxLineDetail->setPercentBased('true');
  $TaxLineDetail->setTaxPercent($tax_dtl['RateValue']);
  $TaxLineDetail->setNetAmountTaxable($tax_dtl['Principle_amt']);
  $TaxLine->addTaxLineDetail($TaxLineDetail);
  
  $TxnTaxDetail->addTaxLine($TaxLine);
  }
 }
 //}
$Invoice->addTxnTaxDetail($TxnTaxDetail); 
 // adding billing email
$BillEmail = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillEmail();
$BillEmail->setAddress('chadha.s@example.com, c.s_consultrctions@example.com');
$Invoice->setBillEmail($BillEmail);
 echo "<pre>";
 var_dump($Invoice);
 
 if ($resp = $InvoiceService->add($Context, $realm, $Invoice))
{
    print('Our new Invoice ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
}
else
{
     print($InvoiceService->lastError());
 print('<br><br>');
 print('REQUEST: <code>' . htmlspecialchars($InvoiceService->lastRequest()) . '</code><br><br><br>');
 print('RESPONSE: <code>' . htmlspecialchars($InvoiceService->lastResponse()) . '</code><br><br><br>');
}
```

Final Invoice Object which is exactly similar with the object retrieved from Quickbook online

```html
<Invoice xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
 <DocNumber>HELLO111</DocNumber>
 <TxnDate>2017-04-16</TxnDate>
 <CurrencyRef>INR</CurrencyRef>
 <CurrencyRef_name>Chadha\&amp;#039;s Consultants</CurrencyRef_name>
 <ExchangeRate>1</ExchangeRate>
 <CustomerRef>4</CustomerRef>
 <CustomerMemo>checking with script</CustomerMemo>
 <DueDate>2017-04-30</DueDate>
 <TotalAmt>108146.5</TotalAmt>
 <HomeTotalAmt>108146.5</HomeTotalAmt>
 <Balance>108146.5</Balance>
 <Deposit>0</Deposit>
 <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Amount>34000</Amount>
  <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
  <Description>Catering -- food &amp; beverage</Description>
  <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <ItemRef>3</ItemRef>
   <UnitPrice>3400.00</UnitPrice>
   <Qty>10</Qty>
   <TaxCodeRef>4</TaxCodeRef>
  </SalesItemLineDetail>
 </Line>
 <Line xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Amount>62250</Amount>
  <DetailType>SalesItemLineDetail</DetailType>
  <Description>Retreat - silver level</Description>
  <SalesItemLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <ItemRef>23</ItemRef>
   <UnitPrice>12450.00</UnitPrice>
   <Qty>5</Qty>
   <TaxCodeRef>4</TaxCodeRef>
  </SalesItemLineDetail>
 </Line>
 <TxnTaxDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <TotalTax>11896.5</TotalTax>
  <TaxLine xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <Amount>7470</Amount>
   <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
   <TaxLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TaxRateRef>10</TaxRateRef>
    <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
    <TaxPercent>12</TaxPercent>
    <NetAmountTaxable>62250</NetAmountTaxable>
   </TaxLineDetail>
  </TaxLine>
  <TaxLine xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <Amount>149.4</Amount>
   <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
   <TaxLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TaxRateRef>11</TaxRateRef>
    <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
    <TaxPercent>2</TaxPercent>
    <NetAmountTaxable>7470</NetAmountTaxable>
   </TaxLineDetail>
  </TaxLine>
  <TaxLine xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
   <Amount>74.7</Amount>
   <DetailType>TaxLineDetail</DetailType>
   <TaxLineDetail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
    <TaxRateRef>12</TaxRateRef>
    <PercentBased>true</PercentBased>
    <TaxPercent>1</TaxPercent>
    <NetAmountTaxable>7470</NetAmountTaxable>
   </TaxLineDetail>
  </TaxLine>
 </TxnTaxDetail>
 <BillEmail xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3">
  <Address>chadha.s@example.com, c.s_consultrctions@example.com</Address>
 </BillEmail>
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for Categories is new in [minor version four](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_quickbooks_online/0300_references/0000_programming_guide/0060_minor_versions) of v3, so it's possible that your CRM and your code aren't using the same minor version.

Comment: We are using consolibyte/quickbooks-php. Can you plz see the below request and response and let us know what need to be change

Comment: REQUEST: POST https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/19XXXXXXX150009/invoice HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/xml
Authorization: OAuth realm="", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",  oauth_nonce="JCqyo", oauth_timestamp="1497421823", oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_version="1.0"
Content-Length: 2702

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><IntuitResponse xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/finance/v3" time="2017-06-13T23:33:23.361-07:00"><Fault type="ValidationFault"><Error code="2500" element=""><Message>Invalid Reference Id</Message><Detail>Invalid Reference Id : Categories cannot be used in transactions.</Detail></Error></Fault></IntuitResponse>